# React native - pseudo elements equivalent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a button with a stripe on top that looks like it's going behind the button (image below).

[image: image description]

I already solved this in pure CSS by using the *::after* pseudo class. But I'm not sure how to do this in React. Any suggestions or help is appriciated.

Comment: There's no you pseudo element in react native. You need to use another element to fulfill this UI.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way by using glamorous div.

```
const IconDiamond = glamorous.div(
  {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    border: '50px solid transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    position: 'relative',
    top: '-50px',
    '&::after': {
      content: `''`,
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '-50px',
      top: '50px',
      width: '0',
      height: '0',
      border: '50px solid transparent',
      borderTopColor: 'red',
    }
  },
)
```

Please note:

- CSS properties must be camel-cased along the lines of react https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style
- when using the content property you need to ensure the quotes are included in the passed string ie content: ''`
- the syntax for before and after pseudo elements is '&::before': { & '&::after': { https://github.com/paypal/glamorous#example-style-objects

Check this for more information: https://github.com/paypal/glamorous/issues/223

To learn more about glamorous div https://glamorous.rocks/basics